# How to find and replace entire cell without matching full cell contents Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, replace

I am trying to clean my data using Google Sheets and need to replace dates with a single variable (ex: 2022-05-03 replace to 3), however the cells also contain time stamps, so it looks like 2022-05-03 11:15. The time stamps vary greatly, so when I do find and replace I end up with 2022-05-03 11:15 replaced with 3 11:15. Is there any way to bypass the time stamp and delete this part of the cell when replacing with the single variable? I want to just replace 2022-05-03 11:15 with 3 for example.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: are you actually using "find & replace" eg: CTRL+H to do this job or you want just a formula in helper column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the datetime values are in column `D2:D`, try something like this in row `2` of a free column:

`=arrayformula( if( isnumber(D2:D), day(D2:D), iferror(1/0) ) )`

You can use then use copy and **Edit > Paste special > Paste values only** to replace the original values with the formula results.